# "Juntar" elementos de um único vetor

Tags: c, array, hexadecimal

Eu tenho um vetor com quatro elementos que são números representados em forma hexadecimal.

O que eu preciso fazer é *concatenar* esses quatro elementos (creio que essa não seja a palavra certa, mas não encontrei outra melhor)?

Por exemplo:

```
int v[4]={0xA, 0xBB, 0x4B, 0x18};
```

Eu preciso de um resultado que seja semelhante a:

```
int resultado=0xABB4B18;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem uma forma só para imprimir e outra que realmente calcula corretamente e imprime:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int v[4] = {0x0A, 0xBB, 0x4B, 0x18};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("%02X", v[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/gtVghM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/JoinHexadecimal). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/JoinHexadecimal.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int v[4] = {0x0A, 0xBB, 0x4B, 0x18};
    int resultado = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        resultado *= 256;
        resultado += v[i];
    }
    printf("%08X", resultado);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/6cKvl6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/JoinHexadecimal2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/JoinHexadecimal2.c).

Comment: O primeiro `printf` devia ter preenchimento com zeros (pelo menos para os bytes a partir do segundo): `printf(i?"%02X":"%X", v[i]);`

Comment: @pmg de fato ambos poderia ter esta formatação, está feito.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, se você multiplicar um número em HEXA por 100 em HEXA, você "desloca" pra direita.

Por exemplo:

> em DECIMAL ->  13 * 100 = 1300
>   em HEXADEC -> 0x13 * 0x100 = 0x1300

Tente aplicar este conceito para "concatenar" os valores em HEXA.

Outro exemplo:

> Se A = 0xE3, B = 0x4C, então A*0x100 + B = 0xE34C.